# Unidentified Unexpected T_Variable error

Tags: php

I am not sure why i get this error, i find everything right. Can anyone help me out?

```
if (str_replace('\', ' / ',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) == SERVER_ROOT) { define('ABS_PATH', '');}
else { define('ABS_PATH', SERVER_ROOT); }
```

What am i missing in this?

Comment: You need to escape the \ with another \.

Comment: `if (str_replace('\\', ' / ',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) == SERVER_ROOT) { define('ABS_PATH', '');}
else { define('ABS_PATH', SERVER_ROOT); }` The \ is escaping the following quotation. Try changing that to `'\\'` as shown...

Comment: works! please submit as answer so i can acceot it

Comment: why not just use `__DIR__`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (str_replace('\\', ' / ',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) == SERVER_ROOT){ 
    define('ABS_PATH', '');
} 
else { 
    define('ABS_PATH', SERVER_ROOT); 
}
```

The \ is escaping the following quotation. Try changing that to '\\' as shown...